# Install MKL using conda on IBM Power 9 machine

Tags: anaconda, conda, intel-mkl

I cannot install `mkl` using `conda` on a IBM Power 9 machine. It seems that `conda` cannot find any suitable version for this machine since `conda install mkl` installs `mkl` on a RedHat machine without any error; though, on the IBM Power 9 with either `conda install -c anaconda mkl` or `conda install mkl` I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mkl

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-ppc64le
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-ppc64le
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I also tried to download `mkl` from `https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mkl/files` and install it `conda install` on the machine, which was successfully installed.  But, after that whenever I wanted to install a new package, I got an inconsistency error by `conda`:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - <unknown>/osx-64::mkl==2019.4=intel_233                                                                                                       failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - <unknown>/osx-64::mkl==2019.4=intel_233                                                                                                       failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                               failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package curl conflicts for:
cmake -> curl
anaconda==2019.07=py37_0 -> curl==7.65.2=hbc83047_0
pycurl -> curl=7.55
curl
Package libcurl conflicts for:
curl -> libcurl[version='7.59.0|7.60.0|7.61.0|7.61.1|7.62.0|7.63.0|7.63.0|7.64.0|7.64.1|7.65.2',build='h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_1000|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h1ad7b7a_0|h20c2e04_2']
cmake -> curl -> libcurl[version='7.59.0|7.60.0|7.61.0|7.61.1|7.62.0|7.63.0|7.63.0|7.64.0|7.64.1|7.65.2',build='h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_1000|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h20c2e04_0|h1ad7b7a_0|h20c2e04_2']
anaconda==2019.07=py37_0 -> pycurl==7.43.0.3=py37h1ba5d50_0 -> libcurl[version='>=7.64.1,<8.0a0']
```

I appreciate any help or comment.

Comment: Intel mkl is available only for x86 architecture (Intel or AMD). It can't be installed for Power or ARM.

Comment: @M.Chinoune, It makes sense. Although, I installed as I explained, though I do not know if it works or not. Is there any code to check if it works?